# PHP exec() - how do I test or even know if its running file?

Tags: php, exec

I have the below code to loop through and run an external file.  I can't find much info on how to do this properly and its not working.

```
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($run)){
    $arg = escapeshellarg($row['shopkeeper']);
    exec("php /var/www/clients/client1/web/products/shopmania/index_test.php \"$arg\"> /dev/null 2>&1 &");
}
```

How can I debug this?  Perhaps its finding the file but the $arg isn't being passed properly, but I have no idea how to test and find out.

THanks in advance.

Comment: Calling PHP via `exec()` from within PHP? Are you serious? Please think very carefully about why you are doing that. Especially from within a loop. Ugh.

Comment: Calling exec() from within PHP is no problem if you do it advisedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just shoud do it like that and have a look a the output.

```
exec("php /var/www/clients/client1/web/products/shopmania/index_test.php \"$arg\"", $output);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: ok, I get empty arrays with this.  Probably one array for each row. If I add 'echo "HELLO"' into the file being generated its still an empty array.  Hhmmmm...

Comment: I can't see a file that gets generated, what are your exactly doing?

Comment: Right, I have errors which are due to including files, which run fine when run from browser but not on the command line.

Comment: Sounds like a environment based problem. The CLI uses a different configuration file. So what types of errors do you get?